# express can't get json data correctly from client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

here is my client ajax code:

```
var sendData = JSON.stringify({
        name: document.forms["token"].name.value,
        password:document.forms["token"].password.value
    });
$.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost:8088/log/',
    type:'POST',
    contentType:'application/json',
    data: sendData,
    dataType:"json"
})
```

and here is my node server code:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require("express");
const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
const moment = require('moment');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var expires = moment().add(7,'days').valueOf();
var token;
app.set("jwtTokenSecret","luo");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.all("/log",function(req,res){
    var name = req.body.name;
    var password = req.body.password;
    console.log(name,password)
    ...
}
```

I found that the name and password are both undefined in node server, the json data on client is correct. I have tried a lot to solve it , but I can't, I need your help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) already serialize data, so, is not necessary to use `JSON.stringify` if you already set  `dataType` to 'json'.

Try to send data as plain object.

Comment: I had a try, but they are still undefined

Answer (score 0):

In my case i make ajax call something like this.

From client side make the ajax call:

```
function _sendData(){
  var host= 'localhost'; //or you can set your host by your choice. 

  $.post(host+'/post',$('#horizontalForm').serialize(),function(response){

    // respose
  });

}
```

From `node.js` server side code given below,

```
var qs = require('querystring');
app.post('/post',function(req,res){

        if(req.method=='POST'){
            var body='';
            req.on('data',function(data){
                body+=data;
                console.log("before proccess = "+body);
                if (body.length > 1e6) {
                // FLOOD ATTACK OR FAULTY CLIENT, NUKE REQUEST
                request.connection.destroy();
            }
            })

            req.on('end',function(){
                var post = qs.parse(body);
                console.log(post.user);
                console.log(post.message);



            })
        }

})
```

and the HTML part be like,

```
<form method="POST" action="/post" id="horizontalForm">
  <p class="lead">

    <input type="text" name="user" value="testUser" id="userId"/>

    <div>
    <input type="text"  name="message" id="messageId"/>
    <input type="button" value="Send" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="getData" onclick="_sendData();"/>
    </div>
  </p>
</form>
```

**N.B :** To install query string you can run the command `npm install querystring --save`
**Don't forgot to include `jquery.js` and `ajax` lib in your html.**

Answer (score 0):

Check `document.forms["token"]` contains `name` and `password` by using `console.log('values',document.forms["token"])` expression .

If values are  there ,

Then call the api,

```
var sendData = {
    name: document.forms["token"].name.value,
    password: document.forms["token"].password.value
};

var saveData = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8088/log/',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: sendData,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(resultData) { alert("Save Complete") }
});
saveData.error(function() { alert("Something went wrong"); });
```

Comment: I tried to delete the contentType configure of ajax and add app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded()), and it works.  I found the jquery ajax can't setting content-type to application/json by write contentType: 'application/json'.

Comment: I check network at chrome that when I set contentType:'application/json', I found that the request headers are not correct, and I consoled the req.headers at node , I found the rquest header of Content-Type is not exist